# How does the hardware know the restart?

Tags: macos, hardware, shutdown, software, restart

A Mac can be switched off via the software. But switching on the hardware cannot be done if the software is not running.

How can a Mac restart when it is switched off? Somebody else has to do that or am I confused? Who turns the Mac back on when it's off?

If this is a stupid question please forgive me.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about a practical problem related to the use of Apple products.

Comment: Is this about how a computer boots, about how electricity is switched off and on, about the difference between booting from scratch, rebooting and wakeing up from sleep, or something altogether? What kind of research have you already done on this (think this is documented in a lot of places)? And, most important: which practical problem do you need solving?

Comment: @nohillside My question has already been answered. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Macs like PCs have ACPI (advanced configuration and power interface) and don’t actually turn off during a restart.

[How does a computer restart itself? - Super User](https://superuser.com/q/294681/156757)

> tl;dr: power states in your computer are controlled by an implementation of ACPI (advanced configuration and power interface). At the end of a shutdown process, your operating system sets an ACPI command indicating that the computer should reboot. In response, the motherboard resets all components using their respective reset commands or lines, and then follows the bootstrap process. The motherboard never actually turns off, it only resets various components and then behaves as if the power button has just been pressed.